# Trying to copy files I do not own from a shared drive to personal drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am an educator and have content I created and co-created on a school google drive. I am leaving the school and trying to take a copy of the lessons I created and co-created. The school drive has files where I am the owner and not the owner in a main folder with subfolders. Our tech person said to try the code below, but I am getting an error and no further support from my school.

I have tried sharing files within the google drive application and then have gotten as far as trying to use the code below by inputting my folder names, but it give me an error on line 22 of the code. I don't know what to do other than open each individual file and manually save it. I only have access to the shared drive until July 26. PLEASE HELP!

```js
function duplicate() {
  var sourceFolder = "5-8 Shared Humanities";
  var targetFolder = "Copy of humanities curriculum from FSMN";

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }
}
```

I expected the code to copy the file structure and all files from all owners from the shared drive to the new personal drive I created. It seems like I am still running into file permissions issues for files I do not own. I am getting the following error:

```
Access denied: DriveApp. (line 22, file "Code")
```

Comment: I am SUPER sorry for the messy format, this is my first post and I don't know anything about code.... I am desperate for help and don't have the necessary support from my school. :(  Please let me know how I can further help. The original code was found at: https://www.naeemrana.com/technology/transfer-google-drive-data-between-accounts-using-google-scripts/

Comment: When writing your post, you have a preview below the text box (as you may have noticed). Code goes _between_ the ticks, not after.

Comment: That aside, this looks like you don't have permission to even read the file, not just ownership... OR you don't have permission to write to the folder you're trying to copy to! I can't really help further, but if your code can do it, you can also do it with button clicks in Drive itself.

Comment: But your files do copy just fine?

Comment: Do you own all the files or just some of them? Or is it the only the folders that contain them that you don't own?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script on stuff that was shared with me, both with modification permission and just read-only, and it worked fine.

That error is usually about drive apps being disabled (which prevents scripts too). See [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#access_denied_driveapp_or_the_domain_policy_has_disabled_third-party_drive_apps)

But since, it works for the files you own, I'm guessing that those you don't are either in 'read-only' or 'comment' mode. As is it wouldn't prevent you from making a copy, but when sharing the owner can check a box to disable print, download and copy options for commenters and readers.

So I think your only solution is to ask the owner to uncheck that box :/

Comment: The school administrator account is trying to help me as well, however some of the teacher collaborators are no longer at the school.  I thought the administrator would have had a higher level of permissions to easily get me all of the files.  Am I crazy to think that?

Comment: No. but if it's from the teachers account the school still may not have those. Really depends on how it was setup. It is sad if you can't get everything, but those teachers did choose to not share it, so I'd respect their reasons, it's their own material. Also, even if they aren't at the school you do have their gmail address, might be worth emailing them to ask?

Answer (score 0):

To copy the files into your personal storage than do the following:

1. Make a shortcut of the folder in your personal drive.
2. Create a new Google Colaboratory notebook.
3. Mount your drive using following code:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount("/content/drive")
```

4. Next, Enter Command:

```
!cp -rp '/content/drive/JAVA_ANDROID/*' '/content/drive/My Drive'
```

Where,

`JAVA_ANDROID` is name of the shortcut of the folder, put the name of the folder you desire to copy and append `/*` to copy all files at that location.

Next is path of the folder where copied files are to be saved, which is `/content/drive/My Drive` in this case.

Edit: I have noticed that in some cases adding `/*` doesn't work. So if it doesn't work the above specified way. Just don't append `*` to the shortcut name and try. So in this case the above command would be:

```
!cp -rp '/content/drive/JAVA_ANDROID/' '/content/drive/My Drive'
```